# How to describe a "noise" which is intentional and not annoying?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word "noise" inherently has a negative meaning: an uncertainty in measurements, or an assortment of annoying background sounds.

What word or term can be used when a "noise" is intentionally produced, for example, the running of an engine, the sounds of a marketplace, or the sound of the wind and birds, etc. to provide a specific mood.

Comment: You mean a background noise?

Comment: You're misusing the word 'intentional/ly' here. The noise of a wind hardly demonstrates intent, and the idea that intent (to produce a noise) always applies where engines are concerned is almost certainly wrong. In many cases, muffling is used. And while Jeremy Clarkson might find a loud exhaust noise attractive, many others wouldn't.

Comment: Simply *sound* would be a quite neutral alternative.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth : I was meaning producing it artificially, for example, electronically.

Comment: The "sweet sound" of the engine roar.

Comment: Neil Diamond simply called it a _beautiful noise_.

Comment: It's called a *noise,* since most dictionaries do not agree with your first sentence.

Comment: Or you could call it **the undin**.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But the sentence ended with clarification about the intent: "a 'noise' is intentionally produced ... to provide a specific mood."   It's not that those sounds are "intentional noise";  it's that they're being produced with the intent of creating a particular mood.

Comment: @Joshua Taylor Recorded sounds being played, or mimicked (eg by a wind machine) rather than produced in the first instance. I'd like to see/hear someone produce actual bird song with the intention of creating an atmosphere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is sometimes called [background](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_noise), [ambient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_noise_level), or bioacoustic noise:

> Examples of background noises are environmental noises such as waves,
> traffic noise, alarms, people talking, **bioacoustic** noise from
> animals or birds and mechanical noise from devices such as
> refrigerators or air conditioning, power supplies or motors.

> #### [Environmental noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmental_noise)
>
> Noise at low levels is not necessarily harmful; environmental noise
> can also convey a sense of liveliness in an area, and is not then
> always considered 'unwanted'.

<sup>Source: Wikipedia</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any common word describing just that. You could use other, more specific words like murmur or rustle, depending on which sound you're trying to describe.

Comment: As Matthew Arnold wrote in the Scholar-Gipsy: "All the live murmur of a summer's day"

Answer (score 1):

Consider phrasing your sentence in a way that frames the noise with a positive connotation. E.g.,

- A whispered hush of autumn leaves in wind
- The vibrant chirping of spring robins
- The gently breathing susurrus of the tide upon the shore

You could also use an an adjective, describing the sound as "musical" or "euphonic."

Answer (score 1):

"Music" is what it is if you like the sound. A broker hears "the music of the marketplace", a naturalist hears "the music of the wind and the birds". Even an auto mechanic might hear "the music of the lifters, clattering harmony with the soft whistle of the fan belt."

Answer (score 0):

> Such a noise could be termed "[cacophony](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cacophony)"-a mishmash of unpleasant
> sounds.

*A type of dissonance, a jarring, discordant mix of sounds that have no business being together.*

Since we are used to the discord, it does not sound annoying.

Comment: The question clearly states that it is **not** annoying. I can't imagine how this term could describe anything that is not found to be annoying... hence "jarring" in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

The word you are after is [euphony,](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphony) which Merriam-Webster defines as follows:

> 1 :  pleasing or sweet sound; especially : the acoustic effect produced by words so formed or combined as to please the ear
>
> 2 :  a harmonious succession of words having a pleasing sound